# An interesting question about sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

> Let $a^{(k)}=(a_j^{(k)},j=1,2,3,...) \in l_{\infty}$ be a sequence such that $\|a^{(k)}\|\le M$ for all $k-1,2,3,...$. Show that there exists a sub-sequence $a^{k_m}$ and $a\in l_\infty$ such that $\lim_{m\to \infty}a_j^{k_m}=a_j$ for all $j=1,2,3,...$

I have problem understanding the question.

Isn't $a^{(k)}=(a_j^{(k)},j=1,2,3,...) \in l_{\infty}$ implies $\|a^{(k)}\|\le M$? Why there is so many $k$ and $j$ here? Why we can prove $a \in l_\infty$, I don't see $a$ can be a sequence?

Could someone kindly help? Thanks!

Comment: I think the notation says that for each $k$, $a^{(k)}$ is a sequence. Then the point is that the same $M$ works for each of these infinitely many sequences.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks! I understand the question now.  However, I have trouble proving it. It is like for every $j$, there exists a $k_m$ such that $ \lim_{m\to \infty}a_j^{k_m}=a_j$,since every bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence. How to take a universal $k_m$ that holds for all $j$? Could you please give me some hint about this? Thanks!

Comment: Show there's a subsequence $a^{(r_m)}$ such that $\lim_ma^{(r_m)}_1$ exists. Call that limit $a_1$, and let $k_1=r_1$. Then, show there's a subsequence of $a^{(r_m)}$, call it $a^{(s_m)}$, such that $\lim_ma^{(s_m)}_2$ exists. Call that limit $a_2$, and let $k_2=s_2$. And so on.

Comment: Any more questions?

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is OK now. Thanks very much!

Comment: Good. Then let me encourage you to write up what you now know, and to post it as an answer.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No problem. Thank you. I am still busy with the remaining homework questions due Thursday. I will post a complete answer after that.